# What characters can immediately follow a parsed PHP variable using simple syntax?

Tags: php, string, variables

For instance, the following will not print `"hello john_doe"` as desired, since `$first_` is not defined.

```
$first = 'john';
$last = 'doe';

echo "hello $first_$last";
```

Maybe there are none?

Comment: Any, if you wrap the variable in braces: `$string="hello {$first}_{$last}";`

Comment: @AlexBlex  Not simple syntax, but obviously what I will end up doing if no other choices.  Thanks

Comment: It is quite handy when you have objects, array, etc.

Comment: When in doubt, use the [complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any character that *cannot* be part of a variable name can be used there - if the character *can* be part of the variable name, PHP cannot determine whether it's part of it or not...

According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

So, to answer your question: any character other than a letter, a number, or an underscore can immediately follow a parsed PHP variable using simple syntax...
(Note that special characters like `ƒ`, `©`, `√`, etc... fall under that `\x7f-\xff` UTF-8 range in the regexp and are valid characters).

*With some exceptions - e.g., you can't use:*

- `[` because it's considered an access to an array key.
- `{$` because it's considered as an attempt to use a variable (e.g., `{$var}`).
- `->` followed by a character that can be part of a variable, because it's considered an access to a property (e.g., `->prop`).

Comment: Thanks MikO.  Guess I should have known this.  There was another simpler question which also referenced this, and I didn't realize at the time the implications.

Comment: `[` would also cause problems.

Comment: `->` could also cause problems, if not followed by another variable. e.g. `$string="hello $first->something";`

Comment: There are some exceptions from the exceptions =) `{` is fine if is not followed by `$`.

Comment: I believe the "very specials" fall under `\x7f-\xff` utf-8 range. e.g. `ƒ` is `C6 92`, which matches the regexp.